# can't use WeakSet currectly in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, set, dataset

I use weakset in javascript and I add two objects to it. One object is local (the object is defined in a function) and other object is global.
This is my code:

```js
const weakSet = new WeakSet();
function gfg(weakSet) {
    const lastName={
        lastName:'ali'
    }
    weakSet.add(lastName);
}
gfg(weakSet);

const name ={
    firstName:'ali'
}
weakSet.add(name);
console.log(weakSet);
```

i have two questions:

1. I try add object directly to weakSet `e.g( weakSet.add({ firstName:'ehyaie' }))` but nothing added. while when write `weakSet.add(name)` it worked.
2. When I log weakSet i received
   `WeakSet {{…}, {…}}`
   but when i open it the result was
   firstName: "ali"
   and i don't understand how two object convert to one object.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me

Comment: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet): _"If no other references to an object stored in the WeakSet exist, those objects can be garbage collected"_. Once you're outside of the `gfg` function, you have no more reference to the `lastName` object, so _can be_ garbage collected

Comment: Why use a WeakSet here at all? It's *explicitly* only if you don't want it to retain references to objects.

Comment: Regarding #2, when you log an object to the console, only what it is printed is evaluated at that time. When you have an arrow to expand, the expanded value is NOT evaluated until you have expanded it, so the value may have been garbage collected and removed from the WeakSet in between when `WeakSet {{…}, {…}}` was logged, and when you click expand.